# Webfont doesn't load, other variations of same font do

Tags: wordpress, font-face

I'm building a Wordpress website and i choose to use the PT Sans font to use on my website. I'm using 6 variations of PT Sans (regular, italic, bold, bold italic, narrow, bold narrow).

I used the fontsquirrel generator to create webfont files and included them in the stylesheet. All fonts are loaded properly, except PT Sans regular. CSS skips regular and picks the next set up font in the css stylesheet. All font files, including the stylesheet that calls the fonts, are in the same directory. No error there (I've checked ;) ).

Still the Regular font doesn't load. I've looked in Firefox and Chrome if i could find any errors in the source, logs or something, but i couldn't find anything.

Here is the css i'm calling. The first one is regular which doesn't work, the second is the italic version which does load. All files are three-double checked and present in the right folder.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'pt_sans';
    src: url('pts55f-webfont.eot');
    src: url('pts55f-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('pts55f-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('pts55f-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('pts55f-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('pts55f-webfont.svg#pt_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'pt_sans';
    src: url('pts56f-webfont.eot');
    src: url('pts56f-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('pts56f-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('pts56f-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('pts56f-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('pts56f-webfont.svg#pt_sansitalic') format('svg');
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem could be? I'm stuck on this problem for a couple of days now.

EDIT:
Tried applying different font-names for each variation. Regular font is still not loading (I see the default browser font).

Comment: have you erased your cache - maybe you have a caching plugin that hasn't updated css since you tried new font-names?

Comment: If the font files and the CSS file are in the same directory then why are you calling to the 'fontfiles' directory?

Comment: @johnnyd23, Good point. My CSS code here is wrong  as I placed an old version of it. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put different names for `font-family` like `pt_sans` and `pt_sans_italic`.

Comment: Tried that one. Still the regular doesn't load.

Comment: Suggestion: check the file permission to see if system can access it.